# Latest message sent by user using discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm trying to write a quick script to get the latest message sent by a user in a small server.

I've messed around with channel.history but can't seem to get it to work. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Hers how you can get the last message sent in a channel using channel.history:

```
@commands.command()
async def last_message_channel(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    message = await ctx.channel.history().find(lambda m: m.author.id == user.id)
    if message is not None:
        return await ctx.send(
            f"The last message sent by {user.name}: {message.content}"
        )
    await ctx.send("No messages sent by user")
```